# Output a pandas dataframe to .XLSB (Excel Binary Workbook) format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to output a pandas dataframe with extension as `.XLSB` using `Python 3` (my version is 3.7.1)? These are huge files (1,000,000+ rows and 60+ columns).

Any guidance on if at all this is possible would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Support  for xlsb is not available  - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8540

Comment: Were you able to open the output file in excel? I tried the `to_csv` method. I am getting a message saying `Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid`. Doesn't a delimiter have to be used?

Comment: its not opening for me, However if you are on windows  you can use open and repair option . update in case you find another solution.

Comment: Just of curiosity , are you planning to use xlsb file for analysis purpose ?

Comment: Yes. These files will be used for some data analysis. Unfortunately, I wouldn't prefer to use the repair option without knowing what the output file contains. These being production files, the risk of data getting corrupted is too high. Hence, I am looking for a solution where no user intervention is required.

Comment: well am not sure if  .XLSB is the right option while handling  (1,000,000+ rows and 60+ columns) of data. Possible chances it will lag.

Comment: @Code_Sipra you might be out of luck... I don't know of any Python libraries that'll natively support writing to XLSB format... (I'm sure there's probably some but they're not likely to be in a fantastic production ready state)... so you're either stuck with XLS or XLSX or generating an XLSX and then automating Excel itself to save as XLSB.

Comment: @Code_Sipra - here you go, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8540 . Consider  Contributing.

Comment: **THIS ANSWER IS WRONG**. `to_csv` creates a CSV file, regardless of what filename extension you provide. Excel can open CSV files, so if your version happens to "repair" it, that's all it did. Of course you get none of the file size reduction benefits OP is looking for. XLSX will at least give you zip compression, this CSV export won't.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for providing clear picture. I am sure you read the comments above.Now go ahead and consider contributing - github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8540

Comment: It seems you were relying on this and i disappointed  you. There is no solution for this as of now and i did my deep dive and shared the details. You should consider reading comments and self check. Just FYI it was already marked -1  and i myself edited the answer and highlighted teh problem @Adam please consider solving than complaining.